# phpmyAdmin doesn't display one table's data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Sorry if this sounds like a very basic question but I couldn't find the answer on this site or with web searches.

I have a table in my database that have this structure:

[image: phpMyAdmin screen shot]

And these indexes:

[image: table indexes screenshot]

It seems something is wrong in this table because I can't `SELECT` data from this table, from `PHP` code nor via `phpmyAdmin`.

I did drop some duplicate indexes but still I have the same problem.

I did `OPTIMIZE` table but still I can't select data.

When I click on the icon to show the `general` table structure, it looks fine. I can select data from other tables in the database. The `general` table seems to be locked or not working correctly.

How can I fix this?

Comment: If possible, use the commandline mysql client, it usually gives the best error messages at least.

Comment: What is the name of the table?  Does the name have any special characters in it?

Comment: As you can see in the picture, the table name is `general` and this table have three `TEXT` fields that contains Persian or Arabic characters besides some of these characters : `, ، ؛ -`